# Strip the high bit from hexdump - convert high ascii to low

Tags: ascii, hexdump, extended-ascii, retro-computing

I am working with an Apple II disk image, trying to examine its contents via a hexdump.

There are strings for various things encoded in the file, for instance, the names of players. In the hexdump, they appear in "high" or "extended" ASCII.

This string:

```
C2 D2 C9 C1 CE A0 D4 C8 C5 A0 C6 C9 D3 D4
```

reads as "ÂÒÉÁÎ ÔÈÅ ÆÉÓÔ", but with the high bit stripped, the above string would be

```
42 52 49 41 4E 20 54 48 45 20 46 49 53 54
```

would read "BRIAN THE FIST"

I'm looking for a way (script or otherwise) to either strip the hexdump's "high" ASCII bytes to "low" or an application that can interpret and display the high characters as their lower equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I can open the DSK in CiderPress, and it will automatically translate the "high" ASCII into a readable form.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for the same answer and never found a way to do it with `hexdump`.

I ended up writing this utility in golang (should be runnable on any platform that supports go).

https://github.com/digarok/hihex